# Lower right half is not rendered

Tags: python, wsl-2, flet

I am studying flet.
I followed the tutorial and ran the sample code.
During the process, I noticed that the lower right half of the screen is not drawn.
Is there any way to fix this?

[desktop app view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJhkV.jpg)

Environment
OS: Windows 11 Home + WSL2
Python: 3.10.12 (pyenv)
flet: 0.7.4

First, I copied the code from the tutorial (https://flet.dev/docs/tutorials/python-todo/) and ran it.
I copied the full code from here (https://github.com/flet-dev/examples/blob/main/python/apps/todo/todo.py).
Then I got the above screen.

Next, I rewrote the end of the tutorial code to the following and checked it in Chrome.

```py
flet.app(target=main, view=flet.WEB_BROWSER, port=8550)
```

In this case, everything seemed to be rendered without any problems.
[browser view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8kY27.jpg)

Since there is no problem when executing other GUI apps (xeyes) or graph drawing code with matplotlib, I think it may be a flet problem.